# Using pattern,matcher in Java

Tags: java, arrays, regex

I have this code:

```
String s = "bla mo& lol!";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]");
String[] allWords = p.split(s);
```

I'm trying to get all the words according to this specific pattern into an array.
But I get all the opposite.

I want my array to be:

```
allWords = {bla, mo, lol}
```

but I get:

```
allWords = { ,& ,!}
```

Is there any fast solution or do I have to use the matcher and a while loop to insert it 
into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]");
p.split(s);
```

means all `[a-z]` would be separator, not array elements. You may want to have:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-z]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting s AT the letters. split uses for delimiters, so change your pattern

```
[^a-z]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `split` method is given a delimiter, which is your `Pattern`.

It's the inverted syntax, yet the very same mechanism of `String.split`, wherein you give a `Pattern` representation as argument, which will act as delimiter as well.

Your delimiter being a character class, that is the intended result.

If you only want to keep words, try this:

```
String s = "bla mo& lol!";
//                           | will split on 
//                           | 1 + non-word
//                           | characters
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\W+");
String[] allWords = p.split(s);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allWords));
```

**Output**

```
[bla, mo, lol]
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is:

```
String[] words = s.split("\\W+");
```